# Does loadrunner record requests and responses to the codegenerationlog while I've paused recording?

Tags: loadrunner

I can marry the request\responses in my CodeGenerationLog.txt with what I have in my Action up to a point, but then there are maybe 100 or more requests\responses in the CodeGenrationLog that don't appear in my action.  I know I paused at several points whilst recording and in some instances, navigated the URL and checked some details whilst I was paused, before returning to the page where I had stopped - to continue recording.

Would my "meandering, whilst recording was paused" be recorded into the CodeGeneration log, even though it doesn't get put into the Action?
NB: Its difficult to work out what is happening in the extra CodeGenerationLog entries - the URL Im recording is the presentation layer for a contact management system - all my interactions are recorded as web_custom_requests containing JSONArrays filled with Hieroglyphs

If not - then what happened?
(I recorded 2 copies of the script, In the 2nd copy it looks like the CodeGeneration log and Action match throughout )

Comment: I don't know why you are even looking at the code generation log

Comment: Where else would I look to identify the response that returned a parameter I want to manually correlate - In this case its the pagetoken.

Comment: Where else would I look to identify the response that returned a parameter I want to manually correlate - In this case its the pagetoken. So.. I need to replace the pageToken with a parameter. to do that I look in the codeGenerationLog.txt file to id the transaction that had the pagetoken in its response. Then in my action I place a web_reg_save_param before that web_custom_request to paramterize the pageToken in its response so I can use it in a later web_custom_request ... Did I misunderstand how to correlate?

Comment: I use that log all the time for correlation.  I find it faster than using the snapshot model because I can search across all requests and responses for the entire sesson.

As to your question on whether the extra items are recorded in your meandering?   I am uncertain.  For myself, when I record I always take a very deliberative approach to avoid catching extra items I do not need/want in the script code.

Comment: Id use the snapshot model but I have to use the tools I've been given - which is a laptop with 14" screen - I really don't have the real estate to correlate using the snapshot view, Its easier to just look at the log in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few times, I can confirm that the CodeGenerationLog seems to capture everything. Even when recording is paused

Comment: Is this an update to your question?  If so, it should be added to the question, not posted as an answer.

Comment: Its the answer. Feel free to edit if thats not clear

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I only asked since it was in the late answer review queue.